# Switch return types based on parameter object's property

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-conditional-types

I'd like to switch the return type of my function depending on whether the type of a property on an object passed in is a string or undefined.

What I've tried is available on the TypeScript playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glsAFgGQPYGMCGAbaBeKAbwCgoyoIA7ALigGdgAnOSgc1PIDNHaHm2OZACYReTFuwC+xYqEiwEiVAFdgaLLigE+EmXOgBxCMACSwCAFsACpkaYLdLUUFRsGHBAD8Y-qygAfKGVKEU4WCCFiaWJOYPRgOFRKKFZjM0sAClQwBKS6WiNTc2tbezoASlp9VE4obNzKOgBtAHI3DQgWgF0KAA9zEMcdNihPBSQVNXdNKvAIGrqcxMbW9o9uvoGhR2DQ8KFR8ZRp6FpKCAA3CEZncig4Woy2k5b75PrlxwAyL6hq2o+eQAdGtNHhwVAWsNWC1yrc7uRGMZlIxki1zAx6OI2C0XJIKNg6NASAjEcjUfDSXcqLR0RBMdCKJQWgAaFxUqDcWkY4BY3ycxis9lUkTc+m8xkiIUc6R3aKSIA), but I'll paste a copy below:

```
type WithLocale = {
    en: string
    fr: string
    de: string
}

type WithoutLocale = string

type GetItemParams = {
    locale?: string | undefined
}

function getItem(options: GetItemParams): typeof options['locale'] extends string ? WithoutLocale : typeof options['locale'] extends undefined ? WithLocale : never {
    if ('locale' in options && typeof options.locale === 'string') {
        return 'test string'
    } else {
        return {
            en: 'test string en',
            fr: 'test string fr',
            de: 'test string de',
        }
    }

}
```

The compiler always thinks that the return type is `never`. I've tried swapping to a generic with no joy:

```
type WithLocale = {
    en: string
    fr: string
    de: string
}

type WithoutLocale = string

type GetItemParams<T> = {
    locale?: T
}

type GetItemReturnType<T> = T extends string ? WithoutLocale : T extends undefined ? WithLocale : never

function getItem<T extends string | undefined = undefined>(options: GetItemParams<T>): GetItemReturnType<T> {
    if ('locale' in options && typeof options.locale === 'string') {
        return 'test string'
    } else {
        return {
            en: 'test string en',
            fr: 'test string fr',
            de: 'test string de',
        }
    }

}
```

I **can** get this working if I manually add a boolean property to identify whether I want all locales or not, but this isn't what I'm after.

Any assistance much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) for situations where a function can return various return types based on some criteria.

You can declare one overload with a [`Required`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype) parameter which is going to return `WithLocal` since `GetItemParams["locale"]` is definitely not going to be `undefined`.

```
type WithLocale = {
  en: string;
  fr: string;
  de: string;
};

type WithoutLocale = string;

type GetItemParams = {
  locale?: string | undefined;
};

function getItem(options: Required<GetItemParams>): WithLocale;
function getItem(options: GetItemParams): WithoutLocale;
function getItem(options: GetItemParams): WithLocale | WithoutLocale {
  if ("locale" in options && typeof options.locale === "string") {
    return "test string";
  } else {
    return {
      en: "test string en",
      fr: "test string fr",
      de: "test string de",
    };
  }
}

const withLocal = getItem({locale: "en"});
//    ^? const withLocal: WithLocale
const withoutLocal = getItem({});
//    ^? const withoutLocal: string
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#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)

---

Caveat; You have to be careful with how you call the function since this approach is purely based on the type of the input argument! In the following example `locale` is set yet due to the explicit type annotation its type is `string | undefined`.

```
const local: GetItemParams = { locale: "en" };
const incorrectWithoutLocal = getItem(local);
//    ^? const incorrectWithoutLocal: string
```

Use [`satisfies`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html) to prevent this.

```
const local = { locale: "en" } satisfies GetItemParams;
const correctWithLocal = getItem(local);
//    ^? const correctWithLocal: WithLocale
```

Comment: Thanks - I had function overloading pencilled in as a fallback, but was just looking to see if it could be done with conditional types in some way.

Comment: Marking as the accepted answer as I can't find a way of doing this with conditional types, and so I'll be taking the approach documented here by @Behemoth